# How to reduce Win 10 display scale of everything to 50% or less?

Tags: windows-10, external-display, display-settings, scaling

everyone! Hey, the mobo on my main Win 10 desktop computer is broke and I can't afford to replace it yet. So I'm trying to use my Toshiba Satellite laptop running 64-bit Windows 10 Pro (an older version than I thought: 1909). I can't easily read the built-in laptop display, so I connected it via HDMI to my HDTV @ 1920x1080 60hz, which technically works fine (barring an unrelated issue I won't raise here) -- except for everything on the screen being humongous!

I've tried setting up the HDTV display as a clone, or an extended display, or as a single, standalone display, but the only change I can make to the items on the display is to make them bigger still (with the exception of the desktop icons, which I can reduce using "{Desktop Context Menu} -> View -> Small icons"). For example, Windows' Display Scaling can only be set to 100% or more. But I want it set to 50% or less! How can I do that?

I'm a knowledgeable user and understand that, theoretically, the Intel HD Graphics 4000 control panel can be used to change the display scale (or aspect ratio or to custom resolutions), but I can't get any of them to actually do what I need; everything stays at 100% scaling or more.  Does anyone have any suggestions to try? How about some registry settings? I already have the latest drivers (for everything). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Although it's impossible to reduce display scaling below 100% under Windows 10, I just found an acceptable work-around, using the built-in Zoom feature.

See: [How to Make Everything Smaller in Windows 10](https://allthings.how/how-to-make-everything-smaller-in-windows-10/)

Comment: Link only answer is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a litle more?